# Android Database creation Error -

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written database/copy database part. but I push the databse through File Explore --> data -> my package -> databse & push using "push file onto the device" option.That time(emulator) when I click data , it showing all data contents. but when I run through real phone, that is connected PC usb port, It didn't allow me to open that data option

see my image:

[image]

If It is open , then only i can push the database to android app.

Reason should be "Permission denied". How can i give the permission?
Please guide me this

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, unless your phone is rooted. The access to the data folder is not enabled on devices.

Comment: +1, yes it is exactly true that you can't explore Data when testing app on real phone connected through USB. You must have rooted phone for the same.

Comment: Thanks for help. I really don't know what is rooted phone? In my phone there is no SD card.please tell me